# How to check if something new appears on a certain web page in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am scraping a web page using BS4 & Scrapy. Is there a way to check if something new appears? If so, can it be copied and printed out?
For example, [here](http://www.flashscore.com/match/0foYiLmk/#match-summary) is a soccer match that is live as I'm writing this post. Each scored goal is indicated by the player's name, it's time, and the soccer ball, which is `span` with the class `icon soccer-ball`. How can I check the page, let's say, every 2 minutes, and print out if someone scores a goal?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP has header `Last-Modified`. 
A big part of [Chapter 11. HTTP Web Services](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/index.html)
 in "Dive into Python" is dedicated to "how not to fetch data"

Scrapy: Look at documentation of [Downloader Middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#)